# Author Tracking Code!

Tags: customization, php, functions, cookies

I need help with coding this piece. Basically i want with someone click on my author page. It stored a cookie of that author name and email. I want the cookie to stay in place untill the person close their browser, or however long. not a big deal. I should then be able to use this info in any gravityform on my site. Basically i am tracking leads generated by my authors. If you have a better way of doing this, i am happy for suggestions. Thanks . Heres is my current author.php code to get the author info

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
$curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
else :
$curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Probably this Question is related to gravity forms. Have you asked in their support forums? Can you probably place a link to that question in their forums if so?

Answer (score 1):

When you are on an `author.php` template page, you should be able to get the current author via [`$wp_query->get_queried_object()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/query.php#L2710). That is also what [`is_author()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/query.php#L148) uses when you want to check for a specific author.

Do you also have a question about setting the cookies? I don't think WordPress has specific cookie functions. [`wp_setcookie()` is deprecated](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/pluggable-deprecated.php#L55) by [`wp_set_auth_cookie()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L663), but that seems to do more advanced stuff than just set a simple cookie.

If you use a specific visitor tracking system (like Google Analytics) I'm sure you can also save this kind of "lead" info with them. If you want to know more about that, the [Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place.